# Angular 7 error while adding multiple themes in my Project

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am using Angular 7 for a particular project. The App is in two parts: The Admin part and the Landing Page. I used AdminLTE theme for the Admin part of the project. As usual, I put the css in styles.scss as shown below:

**styles.scss**

```css
@import url(assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css);
@import url(assets/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(assets/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css);
@import url(assets/bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css);
@import url(assets/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css);
@import url(assets/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css);
@import url(assets/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css);
```

and the javascript in angular.json

```js
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js",
              "src/assets/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js",
              "src/assets/dist/js/adminlte.min.js",
              "src/assets/bower_components/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js",
              "src/assets/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
              "src/assets/bower_components/chart.js/Chart.js"    

            ],
```

**But for the theme for Landing page, I added the css in landing-page.component.ts as shown:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-page',
  templateUrl: './landing-page.component.html',
  // styleUrls: ['./landing-page.component.scss']
  styleUrls: [
    '../../../assets/landing_page/css/animate.css',
    '../../../assets/landing_page/css/icomoon.css',
    '../../../assets/landing_page/css/themify-icons.css',
    '../../../assets/landing_page/css/bootstrap.css',
    '../../../assets/landing_page/css/magnific-popup.css',
    '../../../assets/landing_page/css/owl.carousel.min.css',
    '../../../assets/landing_page/css/owl.theme.default.min.css',
    '../../../assets/landing_page/css/flexslider.css',
    '../../../assets/landing_page/rslider/css/style.css'
  ]
})
export class LandingPageComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor() { }
 ngOnInit() {
 }
}
```

**Then the javascript for the Landing Page at the bottom of landing-page.component.html as shown:**

```
    <i [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/js/js/jquery.min.js'"></i>
    <i [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js'"></i>
    <i [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/bootstrap.min.js'"></i>
    <i [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js'"></i>
    <i [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/owl.carousel.min.js'"></i>
    <i [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/jquery.countTo.js'"></i>
    <i [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/jquery.flexslider-min.js'"></i>
    <i [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js'"></i>
    <i [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/rslider/js/extensions/magnific-popup-options.js'"></i>
    <i [appLoadscript]="'assets/landing_page/js/main.js'"></i>
```

However, when I tried to serve the App, I got these errors:

> ERROR in ./src/assets/landing_page/css/owl.carousel.min.css
>   Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
>   (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: C:\xampp\htdocs\client-portal-app\src\assets\landing_page\css\owl.carousel.min.css:1:2623: Can't resolve 'owl.video.play.png' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\client-portal-app\src\assets\landing_page\css'
>
> ERROR in ./src/app/pages/landing-page/landing-page.component.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../assets/landing_page/rslider/css/style.css' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\client-portal-app\src\app\pages\landing-page'

Please how do I resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: I think the css is looking for some images which it cant get, try removing all url tags and import tags in css then verify if its working, then fix those urls

Comment: @joyBlanks - How? Can you give me a sample?

Comment: `Can't resolve 'owl.video.play.png' ` see this is not available in css folder.